# Material applied to an object is darker than it should be

Tags: materials

I am new to Blender. I do not know how the solve the problem that a material (beige, see screenshot) on an object is shown darker than it should be. I use Blender 3.2.1 and Cycles. The weird thing is that if I place other materials (red and green fabric from the same asset browser) on the same object it is shown correctly.

I read other posts here and tried standard + filmic, exposure 1, clamping 0/0, contrast, but nothing has changed.

Does anyone know how can I solve this ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi. Please don't add "*Solved*" to your question or title. Instead we encourage you to post an answer below with a short description of the solution and what steps you took to reach it. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: I just found the solution (I think, for the moment). I increased the exposure to 5, checking with false color in color management, if there is clipping or not. Now the color beige is beige as it should be, yeah. Thanks @DuarteFarrajotaRamos